# Android "Frozen" Button appearance

Tags: java, android

I have a certain problem: I have created a quick clicker game, where two players try to click quicker than the other one. A special button freezes the opponent's main button. The frozen button currently only becomes unclickable and its text color becomes gray.

To add some "style", I would like to literally freeze it. I don't really know how it would look like, but I thought about a light blue background, and some light blue spikes around it or something like that. I haven't found any style that would do that, and any image to replace the button with, because "Frozen" finds other images ;)...

I'm not a designer so telling me that tools that can design buttons exist won't help me.
Also, just an image won't probably be enough, because the button can be frozen at any moment, with any text and any text color.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I created one for you real fast [frozen button](http://i.imgur.com/7eu3qjb.png)

Comment: As I understand you need a button that looks 'frozen', with those ice spikes around. Rather than trying to do that programatically (which sounds like could use some resources to do the drawing) try instead to design such a button and create an image with it. Then you could programatically set the button in question to that 'frozen' image, when needed, according to the game logic.

Comment: @noev Thanks, but I don't see the button in your drawing.

Comment: @Alex Thanks. See my edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have code, but here is what I would experiment with, if I had to create create the appearance of a frozen button while keeping its text and general appearance:

To ice the button:

- Using Google Image search, find the image of a slab of ice
- Create an imageView with that "slab of ice" image as the src, and make it about the same size as your button (or slightly larger if you want the ice to leak out)
- Place that icy imageView directly over your button.
- Make that imageView slightly transparent by setting the "alpha" property to 0.5 (or whatever looks good, keeping in mind that 0 = invisible and 1=fully visible).

To unfreeze the button:

- Make the imageView invisible.
- Re-enable the button

Comment: That looks great! I'll try it and mark your answer if it works. Do you have a stab of ice image (with white background)?

Comment: Here are several "ice texture" images to get you started: https://www.google.com/search?q=ice+texture

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and edit this answer to tell you if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can create button look (drawable) and set it programmatically.

**Example**

```
myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frozenDrawable);
```

To do some simple looks for buttons i recommend you 
[Android Button Maker](http://angrytools.com/android/button/)
.

**Example 2**

For more advanced look you can create some png

```
 ImageButton myButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.myButton);       
 myButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.frozenResource);
```

Comment: This does not really answer my question (which was probably unclear): I would like to get the image / the xml style file, because I'm not a designer, and don't know how to do that.